# Simple beginner C++, increment and decrement questions

Tags: c++

I'm using C++, and I have increments and decrements down solidly, but I have one equation where I have to decrement `theChar` equation, or the one with `int var` by -2, and I do not know the code for it.

Comment: Please paste your code that you tried so far so that we can help you exactly.

Comment: To subtract 2 from a variable, use `var -= 2;` or `var = var-2;`. I know you're a beginner, but isn't this in your textbook?

Comment: Don't put code in comments, put it in the question.

Comment: Barmar how do I add that? Do I add that to the cout? Int? cin? I have no problem with single space increments, but double space seems to be giving me trouble.

Comment: @RakanElafrangi You don't seem to have a good understanding of the structure of your code - if you did, you wouldn't say things like "Do I add that to the cout? Int? cin?" because it doesn't really make sense. How are you learning?

Answer (score 1):

Please formulate your question better. What do you mean with

> I have one equation where I have to decrement "theChar" equation, or
>   the one with "int var" by -2

Do you mean:

```
char x = 'a';
x = x + 3; //now x is 'd'
int var = 10; 
var -= 2; //equal to var = var -2;
```

Answer (score -1):

The equations are not equations in a math sense of equation.

The `=` sign tells the computer to store whats on the right side into the variable that is on the left side.

```
int a;
a = 5;
```

this stored the `5` into `a` once.

```
int a, b;
a = 5;
b = a;
a = 6;
```

`b` is still `5` because when it was stored it copied from `a`. When `a` changed `b` was not recalculated but stayed as it was.

```
int a;
a = 5;
a = a - 2;
```

`a` is now beeing decremented by `2` since `a` was set to `5` when the right side ( `a - 2` ) is calculated it is calculated to be `3`. When that is done it gets written to the left side which happens to be `a` so at this point `a` is overwritten with `3`;

```
char c = 'B';
c = c - 1;
```

`c` has a value of `'A'` at the end of this code. There is some behind the scenes magic going on.
Characters are also numbers. So what really happens when i store `'B'` into the variable the computer actually stores `66`. You can read up on that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). When i decrement by one the value is decremented from `66` to `65`. The character with the number `65` happens to be `'A'`.

I read in the comments that you have trouble putting it all into a program.
I went ahead and wrote a code snippet for you.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char c;

    //cout is like a friend that you give something to put on the console
    // << means give this to cout
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl; //endl is a new line character

    cout << endl << "Setting a, b" << endl;
    a = 5;
    b = a;
    cout << "Value of a is " <<  a << ". "  << "Value of b is " << b << "." << endl;

    cout << endl << "Changing a" << endl;
    a = 3;
    cout << "Value of a is " <<  a << ". "  << "Value of b is " << b << "." << endl;

    cout << endl << "Adding to a" << endl;
    a = a + 3;
    cout << "Value of a is " <<  a << ". "  << "Value of b is " << b << "." << endl;

    cout << endl << "Playing around with characters" << endl;
    c = 'B';
    cout << "Character c is " <<  c << ". "  << "Number stored for c is actually " << (int)c << "." << endl;

    c = c + 1;
    cout << "Character c is " <<  c << ". "  << "Number stored for c is actually " << (int)c << "." << endl;

    c = 70;
    cout << "Character c is " <<  c << ". "  << "Number stored for c is actually " << (int)c << "." << endl;
}
```